# Understanding time complexity of dynamic array implementation of stack

Tags: asymptotics, stacks

let me tell you first what is written in the book I am following.

*If the array is full,create a new array of twice the size, and copy items.
At n=1,we do 1 copy operation,at n=2,we do 2 copy operation and at n=4 we do 4 copy operation and so on.
By the time we reach n=32,the total number of copy operation is $1+2+4+8+16=31$ which is approximately equal to $2n$  i.e (32).*

Ok ! so far I got it. My question is that can't we say that since by the time we reach $n$ we have $2n-1$ copy operations ,time complexity would be $O(2n-1)=O(n)$?

further the books says

*we are doing the doubling operation $\log n$ times .(OK)
For n push operations we double the array size $ \log n$ times* .

here we performed 7 push operation and doubled the array  $\log 16=4 $ times so what does the above statement say?
Kindly help me calculate the running time in simplest way.

Comment: Are you saying that $n$ is the size of the array before copying? In that case you are doing $n$ copying operations, not $2n-1$.

Comment: I have edited the question.Please have a look again.

Comment: OK, I read it. I'm voting to close as unclear. Who says the complexity _isn't_ $O(n)$? And seven push operations causes three doublings, not four: $1\to2\to4\to7$, and $\lceil \log_2 7\rceil = 3$.